# Can't print class fucntion return with .format()

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, attributeerror

I have a class (named MyClass) with a function (named MyFunct).

when I print it, it's ok but when I use .format I have some issues:

```py
class MyClass:
    var = 2
    def MyFunct(numb):
        return numb + 1

print(MyClass.var)
>>> 2
print(MyClass.MyFunct(5))
>>> 6

print("{.var}".format(MyClass))
>>> 2

print("{.MyFunct(5)}".format(MyClass))
>>> AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'MyFunct(5)'
```

I need to use .format for some reason, and I would like to add posibility to add function :/

Thanks for you'r help <3 !

Comment: Maybe use `f` strings instead? `print(f"{MyClass.MyFunct(5)}")`

Comment: @TinNguyen It works for me. `print(f"{MyClass.MyFunct(5)}")`. And of course you can execute functions inside strings

Comment: what's wrong with just `"{}".format(MyClass.MyFunct(5))`?

Comment: @r0ei you are correct, just tried it out.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it is a good idea to put the [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator on functions like this. Without that decorator, when someone calls it on an instance of the class it will pass the class instance as the parameter (i.e. `MyClass().MyFunct()` is equivalent to `MyClass.MyFunct(MyClass())`), which doesn't appear to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

string.Formatter class in python can only parse arguments, he cannot execute anything
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter.vformat

```
print("{.+4}".format(1))
```

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '+4'

```
1.+4
```

> 5

If you want to execute something use format string:

```
print(f"{MyClass.MyFunct(5)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the expression:

```
MyClass.MyFunct(5)
```

Note that two things happen in a very specific order. To help illustrate that I will write it out as two separate lines of code:

```
f = MyClass.MyFunct
f(5)
```

This is equivalent to the single line mentioned at the start. Note that `MyClass.MyFunct` is evaluated first, getting the attribute named `"MyFunct"` from `MyClass` and returning a function object. Only then is the function object called, in this case with the parameter `5`.

You can see from this that you are *not* getting an attribute of `MyClass` called `"MyFunct(5)"`. There is no such attribute, only `"var"` and `"MyClass"`. But that's what you're asking `format` to do - all it can do is get attributes, not execute methods, as others have said.